# Magento 2 get product id from admin product edit page

Tags: magento2, product-urls, parameter

I am creating a custom grid on the product edit page, for the grid collection I need to filter based on the product id, for that I am trying to get the product id from the URL using below code

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')
```

But the above code is always throwing empty result. Also, I tried to get the value from the registry using the below code

```
protected $_registry;
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry) { 
    $this->_registry = $registry;
}

public function getCurrentProduct() {
    $currentProduct = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    $currentProduct->getId();
}
```

But from the registry itself, I am unable to get the current product id.

I need the product id from URL or else from the registry, how to get that.
Thanks in advance for your support and idea

**full code**

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;

class QuestionAnswerDataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider { 

    protected $request; 
    public function __construct( 

        RequestInterface $request,

    ) { 
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function getData() {
       echo $this->request->getParam('id',false);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
$productId = $this->request->getParam('current_product_id');



//just change the parameter 'id' to 'current_product_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
   $this->request = $request;
}
```

and then use

```
$productId = $this->request->getParam('id', false);
```

Comment: returning empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get product Id.

```
<?php
namespace Training\Crud\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Create extends Template
{
    /**
     *
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context, 
        RequestInterface $request,
        array $data = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Get Product Id
     */
    public function getProductId()
    {
        $productId = $this->request->getParam('id');

       return $productId;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried as per the above code, but still i am getting empty